# Python Requests PDF Content

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, zapier

I am having trouble finding the answer I need for my situation and hoping that someone may be able to help.

Full disclosure, I am pretty new to Python.

What I am trying to achieve is;

1. Perform a HTTP POST to download a PDF (with Requests, Python 3).
2. I want to take the stream and give it Google Drive, which will convert back to a PDF and save the file in the Drive folder.

I am ok with the url file request, but I am receiving `UnicodeDecodeError` on reading the contents. I have tried several files but the same result.

The limitations I have are that I can't install packages (limited to the couple that are provided) and cannot write the output to a file (read-only fs), as I am using Zapier.

This is the (very) basic code I am using;

```
import requests
url = 'http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf'
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
resp_bin = (resp.content)
return {'output': resp_bin}
```

*Note that the file is just a random file I found for testing purposes.*

Error received is; **UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte**

If anyone has a way of making this work without additional packages, that would be great.

Note: I do also have the option of `urllib` here and alternatively JavaScript (node.js v4.3.2) with fetch.

Comment: First, I think in your case you do not need `stream=True`, just `resp = requests.get(url)` and `resp_bin = resp.content` are enough.

Comment: Thanks Sraw, I originally didn't include that, but added after finding an example somewhere. Removing this doesn't change the error received though.

Comment: We cannot help you more if you don't paste your full traceback.

Comment: Oddly enough I'm not able to reproduce this with either Python 3 or 2. Could you give some more details about the error and/or the environment you're running this in?

Comment: Sorry @Sraw here is the full traceback; `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 251, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: I was also incorrect with the version of Python (apologise), it is in fact 2.7.10- I had started this project as a standalone Python script in v3 and then wondered if I could use the environment in Zapier, which would be easier (also thought this was v3). Here is a link to the environment they provide; [link](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/)

Comment: You can't use `json.dumps` with binary strings.

Comment: @t.m.adam - That confirms that this is not going to work for me in this environment, as I can only return JSON. Thanks for letting me know, looks like I will be limited to plain text files only.